# pexpect-how to handle the permission denied exception

Tags: python

Could you please help me to correct my python script. The following script is performing scp to target host using python pexpect module. If I get Permission denied exception I want to handle with a local array variable, containing list of password, and proceed with the scp.

```
local_pass = ["test123","welcome1","Welcome1"]

def file_copy(user,host,password,logfile,local_file):
    print "Connecting to %s as %s" % (host,user)
    local_file_copy = local_file
    remote_file = os.path.basename(local_file)
    print "Performing scp %s %s@%s:/tmp/%s" % (local_file,user,host,remote_file)
    p=pexpect.spawn("scp %s %s@%s:/tmp/%s" % (local_file,user,host,remote_file))
    p.timeout=10
    i=p.expect([ssh_newkey,'assword:'],p.timeout)
    print "setting log file %s" % (logfile)
    fout=file(logfile,'w')
    p.logfile=fout
    counter=0

    if i == 0:
        print "yes to continue connecting"
        p.sendline("yes");
        i=p.expect([ssh_newkey,'assword:'],p.timeout)

    if i == 1:
            try:
                    print "entering ssh password %s" % (password)
                    output=p.sendline(password)
                    sys.exit(1)
            except:
                    while(counter < 3):
                            print "Permission Denied...\n"
                            #p.expect(['Permission denied, please try again.\r\n'],p.timeout)
                            p.expect(['assword:'],p.timeout)
                            p.sendline("%s" %(local_pass[counter]))
                            print "Attempting to relogin....\n"
                            print "LOCALPASSWORD : --> %s\n" %(local_pass[counter])
                            counter+=1;
                            j=p.expect("]","#","$")
                            if j in range(4):
                                    break;

    print "returning expect handle"
    p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
    print "Script file has been copied to target host"
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code looks quite complicated and unreadable.. Why are you solving already solved problems?

I would recommend using the [openssh-wrapper](https://github.com/NetAngels/openssh-wrapper) module, in combination with ssh keys. This makes life easy:

Your code would then look like this:

```
from openssh_wrapper import SSHConnection

def upload(local_file, remote_file):

    conn = SSHConnection('your-server.com', login='username', port=22, identity_file='~/.ssh/id_rsa')

    response = conn.scp(local_file, target='/tmp/', mode='0655', owner='username')
    print response
```

You could also leave the part with the ssh key, if you like to type the password each time.
This code is untested, but should work anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
p.expect(['assword:'],p.timeout)
```

to

```
idx = p.expect(['assword:', p.timeout])
if idx == 0:
    #Permission most likely denied since remote host asked for password again
    ...
```